# Splitting Specific Strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, sorting

I am making an app that requires the user to click on a location and then will be directed to the location via Google Maps.The locations are an array of JSON files. This is what the list looks like when complied... [image]

I have this code to split up my coordinates because the coordinates are backwards in the JSON file and they need to be flipped.

```
var FormatCoords = function(){
   CoordinateToString = location.Point.coordinates.toString()
   SplitCord = CoordinateToString.split(",")
   $scope.Lat = SplitCord[1];
   $scope.Lon = SplitCord[0];
   var FinalCord = Lat.concat(Lon);
  };
```

My question is how do I get the above code to run for a location when it is clicked?

Here is a plunk to my code if you want to check it out... http://plnkr.co/edit/OZZRgiEcrLzreW3lrc5v?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to edit all the coordinates prior to clicking the location.

```
location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
        Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0]
        Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1]
        Com = ","
        location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com,Lat)
```

So when the app loads, it removes the Z coordinate and then flippes the X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `FormatCoords` is global.

```
$('a').on('click', function() { 
    FormatCoords();
});
```

Comment: Im real confused on what you mean by the actual selector. Here is the link to my plunk if you feel like taking a look it would be much appreciated. http://plnkr.co/edit/OZZRgiEcrLzreW3lrc5v?p=preview